# Android AIDL without Remote service

Tags: android, ipc, aidl, android-binder

Is it possible to implement AIDL without the implementation of remote service?
After some investigation of google play services I notice that some AIDL calls executed with the following way

1. Obtain the remote context with the following way

   ```
   Context c = context.createPackageContext("com.google.android.gms", 3)
   ```
2. Get class loader and load class which implements IBinder

   ```
    ClassLoader localClassLoader = c.getClassLoader();
    IBinder localIBinder = (IBinder)localClass.newInstance();
    IInterface localIInterface = paramIBinder.queryLocalInterface("com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.IPlusOneButtonCreator");
   ```

And we can communicate with it!

I wonder why this is allowed and why there is no Service on other side? 
Where do the whole data lives? Does this call starts a new process?

Comment: why do you think there is no remote service?

Comment: I've mock it. No service. really. Or may be it generated somewhere... I don't know.

Comment: ok i believe you, you should read more about Binder, AIDL is just another layer on top of Binder, basically all the communication is done by two methods `transact` and `onTransact`, for example your activity can somehow return a Binder and thus you could "talk" to that Binder, it doesn't have to be a Service that returns a Binder to talk to

Comment: Ok, but, what is the lifecycle of remote process in that case? I can't see any new process in object dispatcher. Really strange...

Comment: i don't know what you mean...

Comment: I mean that in case of Remote  Service implementaition Service lives as long as it has active connections (someone binded) and shut down when everybody disconnects. Process lives as long as Service live. But how this could be in case of no Servcie.... I don't understand

Comment: `IBinder#linkToDeath(android.os.IBinder.DeathRecipient, int)` also read this: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/binders-death-recipients.html